# Extending library activity doesn't call onCreate

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have added a project 'A' as library in my project 'B'. Now in project 'B', I have an activity 'MainActivity' which extends an activity 'SplashActivity' of project A.

When i'm running the app, the onCreate of 'MainActivity'(Project B) is never called, rather the OnCreate of 'SplashActivity'(Project A) is called every time. What could be the problem?

Also what if I want to call the onCreate method of 'SplashActivity'(Project A) and then the onCreate of 'MainActivity'(Project B), is it possible?

The code is given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_activity_temp);
    new SplashActivity().setLogo();//never called
}
}
```

Comment: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` takes it in your `SplashActivity`'s `onCreate()`. Does `SplashActivity` has `onCreate` method?

Comment: Why not using `super.setLogo()` ?

Comment: ya it does have an oncreate..i'll try using your method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own answer ,and thanks to @jimit patel and @ ρяσѕρєя K , I solved it and and if anyone looking for an answer
Code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_activity_temp);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_logo);
    super.setLogo(imageView,this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Just call the super.onCreate at the end of the code , and the code will work just as expected . :)

Answer (score 0):

change your xml ref

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_activity_temp);
new SplashActivity().setLogo();
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
SplashActivity splashactivity = new SplashActivity();
splashactivity.setLogo();
```